# Rails - Updating db variables through my controller via POST request fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, post

I'm working on a rails app where the user can submit a friend name and an address in a form :

```
<%= form_tag "/meetings/#{@meeting.id}/friends/", method: 'post' do %>
    <p>
        Add a friend
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of your friend"/>
        <input type="text" id="address-input" name="address" placeholder="Their location"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="meeting" value= <%= @meeting.id %> />
        <input type="submit" value="Add this friend" />
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Basically there are 3 objects in my app : Location, Friend and Meeting. Location belongs to Friend and Meeting; Friend belongs to Meeting.

I'm routing the form POST request to the create action of my controller, where I'm creating a Friend and a Location object instances where I store data I've received from a GMaps API request :

```
def create

    # Check that the fields aren't empty

    if params[:name].length != 0 && params[:address].length != 0

        # Make the address compatible for GMaps API request

        @address_ascii = I18n.transliterate(params[:address])

        # Geocode the address through GMaps API request

        response = RestClient::Request.execute(
        method: :get,
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#{@address_ascii}&key=AIzaSyDzPiNW9oiPpmL-o1RCVQUVYoT_zk3D3dU"
        )

        # Get status of the GMaps API request

        @status = JSON.parse(response)['status']

        # Check status of the GMaps API request

        if @status == "OK"

            # Get latitude, longitude and formatted address of this friend we've just created

            @lat = @@gmaps_geocoding.geocode(@address_ascii).first[:geometry][:location][:lat]
            @lng = @@gmaps_geocoding.geocode(@address_ascii).first[:geometry][:location][:lng]
            @formatted_address = @@gmaps_geocoding.geocode(@address_ascii).first[:formatted_address]

            # Create instances of Friend and Location, store name of friend and location data into the instances

            f = Friend.create name: params[:name], meeting_id: params[:meeting]
            Location.create latitude: @lat, longtitude: @lng, address: @formatted_address, friend_id: f.id, meeting_id: f.meeting_id
```

Until here, everything works. The instances are created and stored in db. But that's where things get complicated. In my controller, I try to update some variables including values of the Meeting instance:

```
def create

# Code previously shown
.
.
.
.

f = Friend.create name: params[:name], meeting_id: params[:meeting]
Location.create latitude: @lat, longtitude: @lng, address: @formatted_address, friend_id: f.id, meeting_id: f.meeting_id

# New code
@meeting = f.meeting
@meeting.latitude = 49.3
@meeting.longtitude = 2.3
```

But then when I try to show the `latitude`, `longtitude` values in my view, nothing shows up in the browser...

I tried to debug thanks to the rails browser console but all values are `nil`.

Is it possible that I'm not using the POST request like I should? Is there an issue in my controller?

Comment: add `@meeting.save` at the end of create

Comment: @sovalina thank you so much... Obvious yet easy to forget :)